# Why or how does resizeable() solve my "two tk" problem

Tags: macos, tkinter, python-3.8

Like many others, I suffered from seeing an 'extra window' titled 'tk'.
None of the answers helped, until I stumbled on the solution shown below:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

########### Comment out to see the 'two tk' problem
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
###########

button = tk.Button(root)
button["text"]= 'X'
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm running under OSX 10.15.2, with Python 3.8.

Any ideas? I appreciate it might just be my system, but I am interested in what might be causing this. And it's nothing to do with the IDE - the problem is the same when running direct from Terminal:

```
$ python3.8 two_tks.py
```

While 'resizable' solves my problem in the real app, I still would like to solve it. Both Python 3.8 and tkinter and catalina are recent installations

Proof pic:

[image: two windows as not expected]

Comment: With or without the call to `resizable`, I see exactly the same thing - a single window.Are you claiming that without that one line of code, _this code_ produces two windows? That seems impossible to me.

Comment: Thanks for this, Bryan.  Certainly it happens.  But I don't mean two separate windows, just the fact that the root 'tk' window is showing.  See https://www.dropbox.com/s/c62f2ovejjypnj3/xx..png?dl=0 

Maybe it's only in my environment?

Comment: Your code works the same both ways, I think you should try changing your IDE

Comment: HELP!

Not the IDE (Wing 7.2).  Problem just the same running direct from Terminal:

$ python3.8 two_tks.py

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows. Going by the comments it looks like no one else can reproduce on OSX either. Consider a clean install of python and Tkinter.

Comment: You say *"Like many others, I suffered from seeing an 'extra window' titled 'tk'."* but I do not see this in your screenshot. What you have here is what looks like a 2nd title bar displaying the default "tk" title. Are you 100% sure the example you have in your question is the same as the code in your IDE?

Comment: @Mike, yes, I am sure.  No IDE is involved, as the problem shows up running direct from Terminal.  No-one yet has tried it with the same configuration as me, and maybe no-one will.  Python 3.9 exhibits the same behaviour.  But thanks for your interest.

And, there are two windows.   Each of the titlebars belongs to a window, which can be moved about...

Comment: Are the 2 windows identical? have you tried this in python 3.6 or 3.7?

Comment: @JohnT, Yes, same on 3.7.  The two windows have the same title bar, but start off one behind the other, as shown in the link above.  The lower one is the 'root' tk window, which has been the subject of other questions here,  The top one is mine.

Comment: @Mike "many others", should rewrite that sentence.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the built-in version of python and tkinter. Have you tried installing python manually and using that version instead of the system version?

Comment: I've modified this a bit as the meta-commentary was a bit distracting from the main question. Bryan did not get the bounty, in any case - it seems to have been auto-awarded to Muhammet. (If you would like to add an **Update** section at the end, in order to give the latest information about your debugging/investigation, that'd be great).

Comment: No, Bryan, I'm not using the built-in version. I'm using 3.8.1 from the python site.

       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
    
    and tkinter, part of the newly-installed Python 3.8.1, from: 
       
       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter

Could someone  take an interest and run with this current version, on a mac.

Comment: I did include that information, but some kind person removed it.  Maybe he'll remove my comments too....HELP...  

I haven't done any debugging bcause the problem is confined to the one line given,,,

Comment: @JohnWhite: I am the helpful person who edited your question. If I have removed important information, then apologies - you are welcome to carry on editing. I removed three separate complaints ("it doesn't help to say that it works on my system", "I am disappointed that no-one has helped", "Bryan's answer is unhelpful"). That does not seem to be constructive, given that it is **volunteers** who are aiding you. What useful material did I miss? Could you add it back in?

Answer (score 3):

I tried under OSX 10.14.6 with Anaconda Python 3.6.9. However, I had no double window problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Maybe there is a problem with the IDE you are using?

Comment: Thanks, Muhammet, but the problem is the same when I run direct from Terminal:

$ python3.8 two_tks.py

Comment: Same, it seems like the problem is only happening to @JohnWhite

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @halfer: I think you've misunderstood my problem.  The script shown is a simple one that just shows a button. Hence Bryan's relevant comment.  Removing the line shown causes two windows to be shown.    It happens with a fresh installation of Pyhthon 3.8.  Maybe you know someone who could run it on a mac with Python 3.8 and see if it's my problem, or a bug.

Comment: @JohnWhite Have you tried another version of Python? IE 3.6 or 3.7?

Comment: @Mike  Yes, as I said, I've tried it with 3.7 etc.---I did say this in the questions you deleted...Please help me

Comment: @JohnWhite Your duplicate post were closed not deleted. That said I only focus on the details of an individual post so any new details you had on your other post should be placed on this post. That will also bump your post to the top of the active question page for these tags so more people will see the question.